# Mysql connection refused in docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose

I have a problem connecting to MySQL from my golang app in docker-compose. I can connect to db from console: mysql -u user -D data -h 0.0.0.0 -P3306 -p
But, I can't connect when using docker-compose.

My docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./internal/app:/app
      - ./logs:/var/log/parser
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysqldb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf/conf.d
      - ./docker/mysql/logs/:/var/log/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: data
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
```

In my app main.go

```
    dbConfig := mysql.NewConfig()
    dbConfig.User = "user"
    dbConfig.Passwd = "pass"
    dbConfig.Addr = "mysqldb"
    dbConfig.DBName = "data"
    dbConfig.Net = "tcp"
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbConfig.FormatDSN())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()
```

But I get this error:

```
panic: dial tcp 172.20.0.2:3306: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: When you run the script, is the database fully started up?  If you run `docker-compose up`, are there MySQL log messages after the application error?  If you run `docker-compose up -d`, wait 30-60 seconds, and run it again, does it start the second time?

Comment: What is the `bind-address` option in your mysql config file?

Comment: I think golang service start before the MySQL service

Answer (score 4):

I think your golang service starts before the MySQL service. so you have to start MySQL service first then golang service so, use [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) to achieve that.

new docker-compose.yml with depends_on

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./internal/app:/app
      - ./logs:/var/log/parser
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysqldb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf/conf.d
      - ./docker/mysql/logs/:/var/log/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: data
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't help((

Comment: depends_on doesn't guarantee the container will be ready before starting the container that depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but if you specify in yout golang container

> restart: always

, the container will restart until it connects to the database.

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    restart: always
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./internal/app:/app
      - ./logs:/var/log/parser
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysqldb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf/conf.d
      - ./docker/mysql/logs/:/var/log/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: data
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
```